# Connecting to DAP-1320 network after reset

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords, wireless-bridge

I have a D-Link DAP-1320 wifi extender. I have forgotten its admin password, so according to the advices I have found on the web I have pressed the reset button in order to reset it to the factory settings.

Now I see a network called dlink-XXXX instead of the old SSID, but it has a WPA2 Personal password which I don't know (and can't find on the web). As far as I remember in the initial setup the dlink network had no password. I have tried the password I have set before, but to no avail.

How can I access this network?

Answer (score 1):

The default wireless password should be printed on the configuration card that came with the access point, which I'd wager is squirreled away in your closet somewhere. The actual *administration* password doesn't exist.

Failing that, the AP supports WPS for joining your network. If your main router has WPS, press the WPS buttons on each per [page 5](http://www.jmt.bg/productfiles/24901_2075.pdf)! of the quick-start guide. This will make it re-join your existing network, from which you can of course access it because you know the security key for that.